# Specify the embedding of Lie groups (via the representation map) precisely as the embedding of two differentiable manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

How do we specify the embedding of a Lie group $G_1$ as a subgroup into a larger Lie group $G_2$, with $G_1 \subset G_2$ that *agree with a constraint on the mapping between their representations*?

By specifying the embedding, I mean that we can determine precisely the way how the Lie group embedding $G_1 \subset G_2$ is fixed as the embedding between two differentiable manifolds (since Lie groups are differentiable manifolds).

For example, is it enough to give some irreducible representation (irrep) of $G_1$ called $\mathbf{R}_{1,j}$ and some irrep of $G_2$ called $\mathbf{R}_2$, then we dictate the map
$$
\mathbf{R}_{1} =  \bigoplus_j \mathbf{R}_{1,j} \text{ in } G_1 \mapsto \mathbf{R}_2 \text{ in } G_2, \text{ and } G_1 \subset G_2 \tag{1}
$$
would the above be precisely enough to specify the embedding? Is this a necessary and sufficient condition? If not, what else data is needed?

Of course, as Lie group embedding, $G_1 \subset G_2$, the two groups must share the common identity element $\mathbf{1}$. So their group identity element
$$
\mathbf{1}_{G_1} =\mathbf{1}_{G_2} \tag{2}
$$
are the same point on two manifolds.

In particular, we can foresee the case that the reducible rep $\mathbf{R}_{1}$ is
decomposed as a irrep via $\bigoplus_j \mathbf{R}_{1,j}$.
Is there a way that we can enumerate distinct kinds of embedding, given that we restrict the embedding data of eq.(1) and eq.(2)? What will be sufficient to give such an embedding classification?

- I propose that a ***continuous*** deformation of embedding may be regarded as the same class of embedding (if there is a continuous way to deform the $G_1$ within $G_2$, then it is the same embedding). A ***discrete*** deformation of embedding may be regarded as a different class of embedding.
- I suppose it should be some homotopy class data like $[G_1,G_2]$, or the way that the $G_1$ can wrap around $G_2$. But I am not completely sure whether such classification gives an integer value class of distinct maps.

p.s. To illustrate my question further concretely, I will give an example in the next post but a new different post: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/401946/27004).

Comment: You're asking about how to define a map

Comment: yes, in the sense of geometry embedding. please help me to clarify. (I will ask an example next.) thanks!

Comment: What I want to know is like a precise map, for a simple example like the embedding between two vector spaces or two flat manifolds $$\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3,$$
then I can uniquely specify the embedding if I know the maps between two-independent basis vectors ${e_1,e_2}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to two-independent basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3.$ in the form of their basis ${e_1',e_2',e_3'}$. I wanted to know how to specify or enumerate the embedding given the way how their representations are mapped. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the statement that a homomorphism of Lie groups is completely determined by its derivative at the identity, as a map of Lie algebras?

Comment: (But notice that even completely understanding the resulting map $\operatorname{Rep}(G_2) \to \operatorname{Rep}(G_1)$ cannot determine the map $G_1 \to G_2$, since it is insensitive to conjugation on the target by $\operatorname{Aut}(G_2)$ (and hence to conjugation on the source by $G_1$).)

Comment: thanks so much, I voted up your comment, see also my concrete example: https://mathoverflow.net/q/401946/27004

Comment: "the statement that a homomorphism of Lie groups is completely determined by its derivative at the identity" --> actually I am more looking into how to classify possible distinct embeddings if the data of eq.(1) is given. Maybe there are several ways to embed even we fix the data of eq.(1). But I do not know enough math to help me find the precise way to solve or classify this embedding.

Comment: I should clarify that a continuous deformation of embedding may be regarded as the same class of embedding. A discrete deformation of embedding may be regarded as the different class of embedding.

Comment: I mean, the answer to your question is trivial in the sense that you only need to specify the image of each point in the small group into the larger group. Then it has to satisfy the obvious properties. What you explain later is totally unclear to me. You don't need representations to specify an embedding.

Comment: @Fernando Muro, thanks for your input - but please look at this example -- mathoverflow.net/q/401946/27004 if we do not specify the representation, there could be ambiguity. My question is exactly about to give that representation maps, how to "specify the image of each point in the small group into the larger group"?

Comment: There you see that there could be at least two ways to look at the embedding of $SU(5) \subset Spin(10)$. There could be more ways for example.
$$
\mathbf 5 \oplus \overline{\mathbf{10}} \oplus  \mathbf 1  \text{ in } SU(5) \mapsto \mathbf{16} \text{ in } Spin(10).$$
$$
\mathbf 1 \oplus  \mathbf{10}  \oplus \overline{\mathbf{5}}  \text{ in } SU(5) \mapsto \mathbf{16} \text{ in } Spin(10).$$ 
$$
 \mathbf{5}  \oplus \overline{\mathbf{5}}  \text{ in } SU(5) \mapsto \mathbf{10} \text{ in } Spin(10).$$ 
or others.

Comment: If you think these give the same embedding, or you could rule out them, please post an answer. Thank you!

Comment: There's no ambiguity at all even if you don't talk about representation theory. I guess your question is not well explained.

Comment: This is motivated by some gauge theory problems in physics. The conditions given here are also motivated by that representation theory in gauge theory. My post shows what is typically given. I must use the representation theory to specify the embedding (perhaps with more data, which is part of the question: how many distinct classes there are with the given representation map?).

Comment: Are you maybe asking about the possibility of constructing a Lie group embedding satisfying certain conditions?

Comment: yes I am asking the particular embedding(s) that agree with my mapping between representations.

Comment: I update my question and clarify that this constraint in the first paragraph. (you can illuminate or vote up to help on getting an answer.)

Comment: Two homomorphism which are same representations are related to each other by a conjugation by an element of a target group $G_2$.  Let's call this element $g$.  There is a homotopy between $g$ and $e$ (the unit element of $G_2$, which should give a "continuous deformation of embedding", but I am not sure exactly what you mean by "continuous deformation of embedding".

Comment: @user43326, is it obvious that two homomorphisms that do the same thing on representations differ by conjugation?  I'm not even sure I see it for $G$ compact.

Comment: The definition of a representation of G into H, or Rep[G,H] is a equivalence class of a homomorphisms from G to H modulo conjugation by an element of H.  I wasn't talking about induced map $R_O(H)\to R_O(G)$, sorry for confusion.